# Why does the sum of calendar days from 1. AD to 1.1.2001 differ from tropical days by 3?

Tags: calendar, date-conversion

As a little background: in October 1582 the [Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) was introduced to correct problems with the Julian calendar, which was in use until then. The Gregorian calendar specifies the length of a year more precisely, adds a new leap year calculation and removes 10 days from the Julian calendar on transition (moving from 4.Oct.1582 to 15.Oct.1582)

```
 // Julian leap year calculation
 ((year % 4) == 0)

 // Gregorian leap year calculation
 ((year % 4) == 0 && (year % 100) != 0) || (year % 400) == 0)
```

To sum up all calendar days from 1 AD to 2001 AD I use:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int  main( void)
{
   int   year;
   int   daysInYear;
   int   total;

   total = 0;
   for( year = 1; year <= 2001; year++)
   {
     //
      daysInYear = 365;
      if( year < 1582)
         daysInYear += ((year % 4) == 0);
      else
         if( year > 1582)
            daysInYear += ((year % 4) == 0 && (year % 100) != 0) || ((year % 400) == 0);
         else
            daysInYear -= 10;  // 1582 exactly
      total += daysInYear;

      printf( "%d: +%d = %d\n", year, daysInYear, total);
   }
   return( 0);
}
```

Now running this exhaustively over all years from 1 to 2000 gives this pastebin: https://pastebin.com/bR7hwNr1

The most interesting bits show that the leap year and day-skip calculation is correct and also produces the result:

```
1: +365 = 365
2: +365 = 730
3: +365 = 1095
4: +366 = 1461
...
100: +366 = 36525  
...
400: +366 = 146100
...
1581: +365 = 577460  
1582: +355 = 577815
1583: +365 = 578180
...
1900: +365 = 693962
...
1996: +366 = 729026
1997: +365 = 729391
1998: +365 = 729756
1999: +365 = 730121
2000: +366 = 730487
```

Now the question is this: the 1.1.2001 is at 730487 elapsed calendar days. Given the length of the year as defined by the Gregorian calendar as 365.2425, I would expect to see 2000*365.2425 = 730485 days. If one uses [tropical days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_year) or solar days it would be 730484. But 740487 is clearly out of range.

Assuming that no-one miscounted any days in the Gregorian Calendar range, there are some extra days in the Julian Calendar, that don't match with the tropical days. But the Gregorian was created to correct the Julian calendar and I don't think they would have made that large an error in 1582.

This could be more a historical question than a programming question I would guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal of the Gregorian reform of the calendar was to reset the date of the northern hemisphere vernal equinox to March 21, and keep it there. This date was chosen because that was the approximate average date of the equinox at the time of the Council of Nicaea in AD 325. At the time of the council, the date of the equinox had slipped from about March 25 in AD 1.

For all the details read the book [Gregorian Reform of the Calendar](https://www.vofoundation.org/faith-and-science/gregorian-reform-calendar/) which is the proceedings of a conference held by the Vatican Observatory and published in 1983.

To clarify, when evaluating the Gregorian calendar compared to the Julian, using a mix of Julian and Gregorian dates incorporates the one-time correction of 10 days which was intended to correct for accumulated excess leap years from about AD 325 to AD 1582. If one wishes to use some start date other than AD 325, the entire calculation should use ONLY Gregorian dates or ONLY Julian dates.

Comment: Thanks for the link, which is very interesting. (p. 193 in the Lilius article, describes the plan to remove 10 days in 1582, as it was carried out.) I don't really see this answering my question though.

Comment: Instead of starting the calculation at 0 hours 1 January AD1, it should start around AD 325; let us use 0 hours 1 January 325 to be specific, and always use 0 hours. Between 1 January 325 and 1 January 2001 612,146 calendar days pass, which is also the number of days one would observe by counting actual days and nights. Using the average length of the day in the Gregorian calendar, 365.2425, one estimates 1676 years would contain 612146.43 days. Using the average length of the tropical year in mean seconds as of 2000, one estimates 1676 years contain 612146.43 days. No disagreement.

Comment: So basically I am adding days before AD 325, whose drift isn't compensated by the reform. And that's where I am getting the extra days. Thanks!